# Count All functions, arrow functions, class methods from typescript file using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

Im implementing a function that receives a filepath as a paramenter and returns the total number of normal functions, arrow functions, class methods, setters and getters present on the file.

Since there are multiple ways to declare a class method, (eg. `public methodName(parameter 1, ...) , private methodName(...)` I was thinking of using Regular Expressions to retrieve the number of class methods. Something like:

```
const countClassMethods = (typescriptFileString: string): number => {
    return typescriptFileString.match('REGULAR_EXPRESSION_TO_COUNT_CLASS_METHODS')?.length || 0;
}

const extractAllFunctionOcurences = (filePath: string): number => {
    const typescriptFileString = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8');

    const quantityOfNormalFunctions = countNormalFunction(typescriptFileString);
    const quantityOfArrowFunctions = countArrowFunctions(typescriptFileString);
    const quantityOfClassMethods = countClassMethods(typescriptFileString);
    const quantityOfGettersAndSetters = countGettersAndSetters(typescriptFileString);
    return quantityOfNormalFunctions + quantityOfArrowFunctions + quantityOfClassMethods + quantityOfGettersAndSetters;
}
```

My questions are:

1) Which is the apropriate Regex to use to identify the class methods from a typescript file

2) If there are better ways to identify them, what are they.

Ps: I tried looking for this on google but could not find a satisfying answer.
Thanks in advance.

edit: so far I got the current Regex to work for class methods: `"myFileString".match(/(public |private |protected )*\s{0,}[^\n\r\t\v\0\s]+\(\s*([^)]+?)\s*\)(\s*\:\s*[^\n\r\t\v\0\s]+)*\s*{/igm)`

I will update it if I can find a better one.

edit 2: Following @Timo 's Suggestion this is my final Code, in case someone is interested:

```
'use strict';
import fs from 'fs';
import ts from 'typescript';

const extractAllFunctionOcurences = (filename: string): number => {

    let numOfFunctions = 0;
    const delintNode = (node: ts.Node) => {
        switch (node.kind) {
            case ts.SyntaxKind.FunctionDeclaration:
            case ts.SyntaxKind.FunctionKeyword:
            case ts.SyntaxKind.FunctionExpression:
            case ts.SyntaxKind.ArrowFunction:
            case ts.SyntaxKind.ClassDeclaration:
            case ts.SyntaxKind.MethodDeclaration:
            case ts.SyntaxKind.GetAccessor:
            case ts.SyntaxKind.SetAccessor:
                numOfFunctions += 1;
        }
        ts.forEachChild(node, delintNode);
    };

    if (!fs.existsSync(filename)) return 0;

    const sourceFile = ts.createSourceFile(
        filename,
        fs.readFileSync(filename).toString(),
        ts.ScriptTarget.ES2015,
        true
    );

    delintNode(sourceFile);

    return numOfFunctions;
};
```

Comment: You might be better off [parsing your code](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API) and working with the abstract syntax tree. (Google that term if it doesn't ring a bell) Too many edge cases to consider: `const foo = () /* function private () => */ => {}`

Comment: Can you put your own answer in the form of an answer and accept it?